# Flex и Action Script под Ubuntu без использования Wine и VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, actionscript, apache-flex

Программирование на Flex и Action Script под Ubuntu без использования Wine и VirtualBox это возможно? Если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста как. Плагин под эклипс уже не скачать=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне возможно. Несмотря на то, что Adobe прекратил разработку и поддержку Flex Builder и Flash Builder, все инструменты командной строки из SDK будут доступны и далее для сборки приложений Flex. А в качестве IDE можно взять то, к чему есть привычка, например, Netbeans + FlexBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Cкачайте на официальном сайте Adobe FlashBuilder.

Comment: Фишка в том, что на офф сайте уже не скачать